# braintree paypal is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I want to integrate Braintree paypal in my codeigniter website.i load braintree files and credentials from server in my controllers constructor and put other code in a method but it always giving the error Unknown or expired payment_method_nonce.Below is method

```
public function braintree(){
    if($this->session->userdata('user_id') != '' && $this->session->userdata('user_id') != 'user'){
        $user_id        = $this->input->post('user_id');
        $amount         = $this->input->post('amount');
        $inscription_id = $this->input->post('inscription_id');

        $user_details = $this->db->get_where('spm_users',array('id'=>$user_id))->row_array();
        if(!empty($user_details->braintree_customer_id)){
            $CustomerId =  (string)$user_details->braintree_customer_id;
        }else{
            $result = Braintree_Customer::create([
                        'firstName' => $user_details->name,
                        'lastName' => $user_details->surname,
                        'email' => $user_details->email,
                        'phone' => $user_details->telephone,
                    ]);
                $CustomerId = (string)$result->customer->id;
                $this->db->where("id",$user_id);
                $this->db->update("spm_users", array('braintree_customer_id'=>$CustomerId));
        }
        $clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate([
                        "customerId" => $CustomerId
                    ]);
        $card_id ='';            
        $clientToken_new = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
        $result1 = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
                      'amount' => $amount,
                      'paymentMethodNonce' => $clientToken_new,
                      'options' => [
                        'submitForSettlement' => True
                      ]
                    ]);
        if($result1->success == true){ 
            $updateArr = array(
                'amount'=>$result1->transaction->amount,
                'balance_transaction'=>$result1->transaction->id,
                'inscription_status'=>2,
                'status'=>1,
                'data'=>json_encode($result1),
                'payment_method'        => 'Braintree',
                'payment_date'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                );
                $this->db->where("id",$inscription_id);
                $this->_db->update("spm_inscription", $updateArr);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Inscription Payment Success');
                redirect('frontend/paypalpayment/'.$inscription_id);
        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Payment failed');
            redirect('frontend/paypalpayment/'.$inscription_id);
        }    
    }else{
        redirect('frontend');
    } 
}
```

and here is my constructor

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    require_once '/home/public_html/mysite/braintree/Braintree.php';
    Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
    Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('zxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd');
    Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('7xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx7');
    Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8');
}
```

i tried google but no luck.please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).</sub>

From the [documentation on `Transaction:sale()`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/php):

> To create a transaction, you must include an amount and either a paymentMethodNonce or a paymentMethodToken.

The parameter that you're passing in your `paymentMethodNonce` parameter is not a [payment method nonce](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method-nonce/php). Instead, you're passing it a [client token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/php), which is causing it to fail. These items are similarly-named, but have very different purposes.

- **Client token**: contains configuration information about your gateway account. The [client-side SDKs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3#get-a-client-token) use them to set up their own configuration correctly and work seamlessly with your server, and they should not be passed to transaction sale calls.
- **Payment method nonce**: a reference to a set of tokenized payment method information, such as a credit card number and expiration date. These are generally produced by the [tokenize](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v3#send-payment-method-nonce-to-server) calls in the client-side SDKs after a user enters credit card information.
- **Payment method token**: a reference to a payment method that you've saved in your Braintree account.

To create a transaction properly in your code, you'll have to either reference a payment method that you've saved in your vault (by using a payment method token), or reference a set of newly-tokenized payment method information that a customer submitted on your website (by using a payment method nonce). For example, if you were to save the customers' payment method tokens in your database, you might run something like this:

```
    if (!empty($user_details->braintree_customer_id)) {
        $CustomerId = (string) $user_details->braintree_customer_id;
        $CustomerSavedPaymentMethod = (string) $user_details->payment_method_token;
    } else {
        ...
    }

    $result1 = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
        'amount' => $amount,
        'paymentMethodToken' => $CustomerSavedPaymentMethod,
        'options' => [
            'submitForSettlement' => True
        ]
    ]);
```

If you need some additional resources to create a payment method nonce and pass it back to your server, you can reference [our full PHP integration example](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php_example).